# Invalid ID error when running javascript function in visual studio 2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I work in visual studio.
I get a runtime error: id invalid when I click on a button a javascript function is called, that works with the element id. 
But I can see the element with exact id in view source of the page, 
where is the problem ?
i use just html element and get same error.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>View HTML</title>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 Hmove=-100;
 function moveObjRight(obj) 
{    
obj.style.left=Hmove;
Hmove+=2;
if(Hmove<100)
    window.setTimeout("moveObjRight(" +obj.id+ ");", 0);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnViewHtml" runat="server" Text="View Html" onclick="moveObjRight(JS)"/>
<IMG SRC="starflower.gif" ALT="Starflower" id="JS">
    <br />
    <br />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post a bit of your code, that would make us help you better..

Comment: here is sample code of what i want to do

Comment: After If Condition replace your code with this Window.setTimeout("moveObjRight('" +obj.ID + "')",0); 
tell whether is it working ??

Comment: if(Hmove<100)
   Window.setTimeout("moveObjRight('" +obj.ID + "')",0);
}

Answer (score 0):

Button has already got ID on client, which is not JS

> asp:Button ID="btnViewHtml"

I think that is cause of your problems

Comment: i want run javascript function for the image and the id is : JS

Answer (score 0):

You need `OnClientClick`, not `OnClick`:

```
<asp:Button 
    ID="btnViewHtml" 
    runat="server" Text="View Html" 
    OnClientClick="moveObjRight(this); return false;"
/>
```

Also note the argument passed to the of the `moveObjRight` function: `this`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the id of the button and the referencing it as a object in the code...

Instead of that use this
`<asp:Button ID="btnViewHtml" runat="server" Text="View Html" onclick="moveObjRight(document.getElementById('JS'))"/>`

and in the script use this

`window.setTimeout("moveObjRight(" +obj+ ");", 0);`